# Will combinelatest trigger doOnUnsubscribe of its children

Tags: rx-java

Not sure if the combined observable delegates doonunsubscribe to its sources.

If not is there a simple way to trigger the unsubscribles of its children?

In code:

```
observable o = observable.combinelatest(o1, o2);
```

If something triggers unsubscribe of o will it trigger the unsubscribe of o1 and o2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean.

Unsubscription is propagated to both `o1` and `o2` but if you want to perform custom actions, you have to use `doOnUnsubscribe` on all relevant parties:

```
Observable<T> o = Observable.combineLatest(
    o1.doOnUnsubscribe(() -> { }),
    o2.doOnUnsubscribe(() -> { }))
.doOnUnsubscribe(() -> { });

o.take(1).subscribe();
```

But note that these are chain-global (instead of per-subscriber) actions and a second subscription/unsubscription to `o` may call them again. If you need per-subscriber resource management, look at the `using` operator.

Comment: so you are saying when o's doOnUnsubscribe is called, both o1 and o2's doOnUnsubscribe will be called?

Comment: Yes, unless the stream they run on is one of the standard schedulers in which case your main program may exit before the actions have a chance to run.