# Subscribe to both route params and queryParams in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have set up the following **routing system**

```ts
export const MyRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'new', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: ':type', component: MyComponent}
];
```

and have the following **navigation system**

```ts
goToPage('new');
goToPageNo('new', 2);

goToPage(type) {
  this.router.navigate([type]);
}
goToPageNo(type, pageNo) {
  this.router.navigate([type], {queryParams: {page: pageNo}});
}
```

Sample **URL** looks like this

> http://localhost:3000/new
>
> http://localhost:3000/new?page=2
>
> http://localhost:3000/updated
>
> http://localhost:3000/updated?page=5

*Sometimes they have **optional** queryParams* (page)

Now I need to read both **route params and queryParams**

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.paramsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((param: any) => {
    this.type = param['type'];
    this.querySubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((queryParam: any) => {
      this.page = queryParam['page'];
      if (this.page)
        this.goToPageNo(this.type, this.page);
      else
        this.goToPage(this.type);
    })
  })
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.paramsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  this.querySubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Now this is not working as expected, visiting pages without queryParams works, then of I visit a page with queryParams "goToPageNo" gets called multiple times, as I am subscribing to queryParams inside route params.

I looked at the Angular 2 documentation, they do not have any example or codes where a subscription to **both route params and queryParams** is implemented at the same time.

Any way to do this properly? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For Angular 6+

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.queryParams)
    .pipe(map(results => ({params: results[0].xxx, query: results[1]})))
    .subscribe(results => {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Where `xxx` is from your route

`{path: 'post/:xxx', component: MyComponent},`

Note for Angular 12+ (i.e. RxJs version 7+), use:

```
import { combineLatest, map } from 'rxjs';
```

and pass an array to the `combineLatest` function:

```
combineLatest([this.route.params, this.route.queryParams])
    .pipe(map(results => ({params: results[0].xxx, query: results[1]})))
    // ...
```

Comment: Note that this, of course, relies on both `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';` and `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: but it's fire twice from post/:xxx?page=1 to 'post/:xxx'

Comment: @maidanh can u provide an example on stackblitz

Comment: See my link demo https://angular-ev2rns-subscribe-param-and-path-param.stackblitz.io
First I hit on cat1, cat2, or cat3. 
Second I hit on page1, page2, page3.
It's okie now.
When I hit back to cat1, cat2, cat3 it trigger twice

Comment: Open console to see the log

Comment: @maidanh this is super wired, i think u should create a new issue about this problem  - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: @ThunderRoid I created a post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283605/how-to-detect-url-change-in-angular-7-include-param-and-query-param.

And I see there was an issue it seem related to it. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21124

Comment: @maidanh did you find any solution , it tigers twice

Comment: @HemanthSP I worked around with this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283605/how-to-detect-url-change-in-angular-7-include-param-and-query-param
But there was a comment in that post but I dit not try it yet

Comment: I tried that comment it's working fine because I also face same issue

Comment: In Angular 9 (maybe earlier too), to avoid a `deprecated` warning, use `combineLatest([this.route.params, this.route.queryParams])`

Answer (score 55):

I managed to get a single subscription to both the queryParams and Params by combining the observables by using `Observable.combineLatest` before subscribing.

Eg.

```
var obsComb = Observable.combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.queryParams, 
  (params, qparams) => ({ params, qparams }));

obsComb.subscribe( ap => {
  console.log(ap.params['type']);
  console.log(ap.qparams['page']);
});
```

Comment: Wow, it works, awesome, thanks so much. BTW, wanted to ask you, don't we need to 'unsubscribe' this in ngOnDestroy() function ?

Comment: Well I've not been unsubscribing generally based on  [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-angular-2-http-calls-to-prevent-memory-leak) but hadn't thought more about combineLatest but believe it will propagate down, [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122768/will-combinelatest-trigger-doonunsubscribe-of-its-children). In my first month of the love hate relationship with angular 2 (more hate so far tbh :)) so not 100%.

Comment: How does it actually help? If I change at the same time both query and path parameters my callback is fired twice.

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

Comment: @joycollector any work around for that? I stuck on the same

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot actually I switched to react :)

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I also ran into an issue where combineLatest on route params and fragment emitted two values when navigating. I worked around it by piping the combineLatest observable through debounceTime(1).

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot debounceTime(0) should work as well

Comment: @joycollector I know it is late. But probably you can use debounceTime rxjs operator which will ignore first emit. Setting value to 1 probably good option if the observables triggerend not asynchronously

Comment: @TheodoreBrown, the debounceTime(1) fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Late answer, but another solution :
Instead of subscribing to the params and queryparams I subscribe to the NavigationEnd event on the router. Fires only once and both params and queryparams are available on snapshot : (example for angular 4)

```
this.router.events.filter(event=>event instanceof NavigationEnd)
   .subscribe(event=>{
       let yourparameter = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params.yourparameter;
       let yourqueryparameter = this.activatedroute.snapshot.queryParams.yourqueryparameter;
   });
```

Regarding unsubscribing : yes it is true routing params, queryParams or navigation events subscriptions are automatically unsubscribed by the router, there is however one exception : if your route has children , when navigating between children, no unsubscribe will occur. Only when you navigate away from the parent route!

E.g. I had a situation with tabs as child routes. In constructor of first tab component subscribing on route params to retrieve data. Each time I navigate from first to second tab and back another subscription was added resulting in multiplying the number of requests.

Comment: This works for the case that either the `param` or `queryParam` changes - and only triggers once if both change. Great answer

Comment: Great solution that worked for me. Regarding the unsubscribe you could avoid this by wrapping the subscription in a service and publish the values using an rxjs subject. Your components can then subscribe to the subjects of the service (or observables created from them). That way only one subscription for the router events will be opened.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative (on Angular 7+) is to subscribe to the ActivatedRoute url observable and use "withLatestFrom" to get the latest paramsMap and queryParamsMap. It appears that the params are set before the url observable emits:

```
this.route.url.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.route.paramMap, this.route.queryParamMap)
).subscribe(([url, paramMap, queryParamMap]) => {
  // Do something with url, paramsMap and queryParamsMap
});
```

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom

https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Thank you so much. Half of the people here don't understand the fundamental issue of sometimes needing queryParams and sometimes only params.

Answer (score 7):

Following Shifatul's answer, this supposes working for the observables changed at the same time and just fire once:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.queryParams)
    .pipe(map(results => ({params: results[0].xxx, query: results[1]})), debounceTime(0))
    .subscribe(results => {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Shifatul's answer extended for ...

- Angular 9+ (using an array for combineLastest) and
- simpler syntax (using typescript array parameter decomposition):

```ts
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

combineLatest([this.route.params, this.route.queryParams])
    .subscribe(([params, queryParams]) => {
        console.log("your route data:", params, queryParams);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solutions using `combineLatest` do not work properly. After the first route change, you will get an event every time the `param` or `queryParam` value changes, which means you get calls in an intermediate state when one has changed but the other has not, very bad.

@rekna's solution pretty much works for me, except I wasn't getting an event when my app was first loaded, so here's my modification to @rekna's solution:

```
this.routeUpdate(this.activatedRoute.snapshot);
this.routeSubscription = this.router.events
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe(event => this.routeUpdate(this.activatedRoute.snapshot));
```

Where `routeUpdate` is a method to do whatever parameter handling is required.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ActivatedRouteSnapshot`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html) from your  `ActivatedRoute`

`ActivatedRouteSnapshot` interface has `params` and `queryParams` property, and you could get the both value at the same time.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params);
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
}
```

Edit : As OP stated, we only get the initial value of the parameters with this technique.

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dNjQPjvsFcTkVSOG7QfG?p=preview)

Comment: Not working for multiple links: https://plnkr.co/edit/BQRbI5CrPNglvSB6NR2r

Comment: if you `zip` both you would only execute `onNext` when both of them emit, that's why `combineLatest` would be a better operator choice.

Comment: The snapshot won’t get updated if we try to reload the current route with different route parameters...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use zip operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html

Because if you use combineLatest and change url params or query params you got value with new query params and old url params.

Urls for example:

http://localhost/1?value=10

http://localhost/2?value=20

http://localhost/3?value=30