# Angular 2 route not reloading component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have following code

```
{
    path: 'clientReports',
    component: ClientsRootComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':reportId',
            component: ClientsReportComponent,          
            children: [
                {
                    path: ':countryId/:branchId',
                    component: ClientsGridComponent,                    
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and following links

```
app/clientReports/1/1/1
app/clientReports/2/1/1
app/clientReports/3/1/1
```

Whenever I click a link I can see that `ClientsReportComponent` does not reload and instead existing one is being reused and caused me problem with the services lifetime that are declared in the providers of this component.

Shouldn't be the component `ClientsReportComponent` reloaded every time a new link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are already in same component it wont reload the component.
If you want to do something on route param changes the component you are already in, then you have to subscribe for queryParam/routeparam changes.

Please find below stack link

[Router Param Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699229/subscribe-to-both-route-params-and-queryparams-in-angular-2)

Comment: ClientsRootComponent has some services injected that I need to destroy and reuse. Thus reusing the component is essential for me

Comment: In that case cant you use EventEmitter and subscribe from parent component?

Comment: Is there any way to override this behavior?