# Subscribe to both route data and params

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to subscribe to both route data and route params in Angular. I am using `Observable.zip`, but unfortunately subscribe function isn't trigger when I switch routes (I have routes A, B, C and D which has a parameter in URL).

My code looks as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = Observable.zip(this.route.data, this.route.params)
      .subscribe(([data, params]) => {
         // do something...
      });
  }
```

However, when I use these piece of code:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((data) => {
  // do something...
})
```

Everything works fine and I am able to subscribe to params. I want to do this using only one subscription.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscribe to both route params and queryParams in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699229/subscribe-to-both-route-params-and-queryparams-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `zip` operator emits only when all source Observables emit the same number of items.

It looks like for you it'll be better to use `combineLatest` that emits after all source Observables emitted at least one item and then on every emission.

You can also append `startWith` and initialize `combineLatest` with `null`s.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.route.data.startWith(null),
  this.route.params.startWith(null),
  (data, params) => {
    ...
  }
).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `forkJoin` , something like this :

```
const combined = Observable.forkJoin(
  this.route.data,
  this.route.params
)

combined.subscribe(latestValues => {
    const [ route_data , route_params ] = latestValues;
    console.log( "route_data" , route_data);
    console.log( "route_params" , route_params);
});
```